# Leather flavour

Tags: flavor, chocolate

A long time ago (ten years I think) I had leather, mint and tobacco chocolates at the Fat Duck.

I've made pretty good tobacco ones, and I've been trying to work out how to do the leather ones.

My first instinct is to get some leather and isi infuse it into booze. Gold standard would be to rotovap that to get the flavor on its own, but unsurprisingly I don't have a rotovap.

1) Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do it?

2) what about the safety of leather. Eating chrome tanned leather is probably like using a plutonium fork. But what about veg tanned stuff?

3) is there a way to skip the leather completely and get the flavor some other way?

Comment: Perhaps rawhide dog chews?

Comment: The vegan version, made by cooking out pleather, turned out just as bad as the healthier version made by throwing in an e-cigarette...

Answer (score 1):

How about using Adam from Hair of the Dog beer? It is noted especially for its taste of fine leather. Honest and not kidding.

It is also noted that it's tastes great with chocolate and cigars, so I bet you could somehow make use of it.

[Adam - Hair of the Dog](https://www.hairofthedog.com/beers/)